# Getting substrings in between delimiters multiple times from one string without looping

Tags: awk, sed, grep, xml

I have looked all over for a solution to this, but I couldn't find one.

I am using `qstat -x` to pass a large string of job information. The output from `qstat -x` is in XML format. The substrings I am looking for reside between two explicit delimiters, `<Output_Path>` and `</Output_Path>`. Here is an example of some of the output from `qstat -x`, with sensitive information censored out:

```
<Data><Job><Job_Id>4382.xxxxxxxx.xx.xxxxxxx</Job_Id><Job_Name>r053_x.xxMx.xxR_400k_neos2.pbs</Job_Name><Job_Owner>xxxxxxxx@xxxxxxxx.xx.xxxxxxx</Job_Owner><job_state>H</job_state><queue>default</queue><server>xxxxxxxx.xx.xxxxxxx</server><Checkpoint>u</Checkpoint><ctime>1466396941</ctime><Error_Path>xxxxxxxx.xx.xxxxxxx:/data/xxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxx/summer2016/relax/r053_x.xxMx.xxR_400k_neos2/r053_x.xxMx.xxR_400k_neos2.pbs.e4382</Error_Path><Hold_Types>u</Hold_Types><Join_Path>n</Join_Path><Keep_Files>n</Keep_Files><Mail_Points>a</Mail_Points><mtime>1466423857</mtime><Output_Path>xxxxxxxx.xx.xxxxxxx:/data/xxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxx/summer2016/relax/r053_x.xxMx.xxR_400k_neos2/r053_x.xxMx.xxR_400k_neos2.pbs.o4382</Output_Path><Priority>0</Priority><qtime>1466396941</qtime><Rerunable>True</Rerunable><Resource_List><cput>9999:59:59</cput><nodect>1</nodect><nodes>1:ppn=12:gpus=1</nodes><walltime>2400:00:00</walltime></Resource_List><comment>Not Running: Not enough of the right type of nodes are available</comment><submit_args>r053_x.xxMx.xxR_400k_neos2.pbs</submit_args><fault_tolerant>False</fault_tolerant><job_radix>0</job_radix><submit_host>xxxxxxxx.xx.xxxxxxx</submit_host></Job><Job><Job_Id>4396.xxxxxxxx.xx.xxxxxxx</Job_Id><Job_Name>0R_20k_neos2.pbs</Job_Name><Job_Owner>xxxxxxxx@xxxxxxxx.xx.xxxxxxx</Job_Owner><job_state>H</job_state><queue>default</queue><server>xxxxxxxx.xx.xxxxxxx</server><Checkpoint>u</Checkpoint><ctime>1466606895</ctime><Error_Path>xxxxxxxx.xx.xxxxxxx:/data/xxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxx/summer2016/relax/r061_x.xxMx.xxR_20k_neos2/0R_20k_neos2.pbs.e4396</Error_Path><Hold_Types>u</Hold_Types><Join_Path>n</Join_Path><Keep_Files>n</Keep_Files><Mail_Points>a</Mail_Points><mtime>1466609370</mtime><Output_Path>xxxxxxxx.xx.xxxxxxx:/data/xxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxx/summer2016/relax/r061_x.xxMx.xxR_20k_neos2/0R_20k_neos2.pbs.o4396</Output_Path><Priority>0</Priority>
```

I want to get all substrings that reside between every iteration of `<Output_Path>` and `</Output_Path>`. That is, if I had the string

```
<Output_Path>xxxxxxxx.xx.xxxxxxx:/data/xxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxx/summer2016/relax/r061_x.xxMx.xxR_20k_neos2/0R_20k_neos2.pbs.o4396</Output_Path><Output_Path>xxxxxxxx.xx.xxxxxxx:/data/xxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxx/summer2016/relax/r053_x.xxMx.xxR_400k_neos2/r053_x.xxMx.xxR_400k_neos2.pbs.o4382</Output_Path>
```

I would want a command that returns

```
xxxxxxxx.xx.xxxxxxx:/data/xxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxx/summer2016/relax/r061_x.xxMx.xxR_20k_neos2/0R_20k_neos2.pbs.o4396
xxxxxxxx.xx.xxxxxxx:/data/xxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxx/summer2016/relax/r053_x.xxMx.xxR_400k_neos2/r053_x.xxMx.xxR_400k_neos2.pbs.o4382
```

or

```
xxxxxxxx.xx.xxxxxxx:/data/xxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxx/summer2016/relax/r061_x.xxMx.xxR_20k_neos2/0R_20k_neos2.pbs.o4396 xxxxxxxx.xx.xxxxxxx:/data/xxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxx/summer2016/relax/r053_x.xxMx.xxR_400k_neos2/r053_x.xxMx.xxR_400k_neos2.pbs.o4382
```

But I need it done without using any slow `for` loops. I tried using variations on `awk`, `grep`, and `sed`, but couldn't find anything that worked.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are other alternatives such as a one-line perl script acceptable?

Comment: Since you changed the formatting, in the question, it might not be bad to show a real sample of the input data. Especially if there is extra data before/after the first and last delimiters or between them (e.g. you only want the `foo` and `bar` in `xxx<a>foo<b>yyy<a>bar<b>zzz`).

Comment: They are specifically full path names between each alternating delimiter. I am hesitant to release a full example because I am working with sensitive scientific information.

Comment: I updated the main post to provide a much more specific example. Hopefully this will help in answering the question.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, then:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -v //Output_Path -nl data.xml
```

Answer (score 1):

If your system's grep supports PCRE, you could maybe do

```
$ echo 'aaa string1 bbb aaa string2 bbb aaa string3 bbb' | 
  grep -oP '(?<=(aaa|bbb) )\w*?(?= (aaa|bbb))'
string1
string2
string3
```

or if you need to handle more general amounts of surrounding whitespace

```
$ echo 'aaa string1 bbb aaa string2 bbb aaa string3 bbb' |
  grep -oP '(aaa|bbb)\s+\K\w*?(?=\s+(aaa|bbb))'
string1
string2
string3
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are fine with something structured like:

```
string1
string2
string3
```

I would just simply replace you delimiters with a newline. Something such as this should get you close:

```
sed "s/\(aaa\)\|\(bbb\)/\n/g" test.txt
```

**Edit**

As pointed out by @clk below, my first answer may give double newlines. Changing to something such as:

```
sed "s/\(\s\)\?aaa\(\s\)\?/bbb/g" test.txt | sed "s/b*//g"
```

for me yields:

```
 string1 string2 string3
```

which also works the same when piped in, such as:

```
echo 'aaa string1 bbb aaa string2 bbb aaa string3 bbb' | sed "s/\(\s\)\?aaa\(\s\)\?/bbb/g" | sed "s/b*//g"
```

Not a very *pretty* answer, but quick and dirty and gives you the format you're asking for.

Comment: As written, won't this produce extra lines in between the strings?

Comment: I should add to the main post that I am using the command `qstat -x` as my input. To my knowledge, this can be passed through a pipeline and also through the `<()` syntax. I am thus getting the error `sed: -e expression #1, char 41: unknown option to \`s'`

Comment: how about just sed 's/aaa//g;s/bbb/\n/g;' to delete the starting delimiter and replace only the ending with a newline?

Answer (score 0):

To parse XML, use an XML parser.

[XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/) is a command line XML parser that is very good for this sort of situation.

Assuming that your XML is complete (it's missing `</Job></Data>` at the end as it is written now) then you can extract the value of the `Output_Path` node with

```
$ xmlstarlet t -v '//Output_Path' -nl input.xml
xxxxxxxx.xx.xxxxxxx:/data/xxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxx/summer2016/relax/r053_x.xxMx.xxR_400k_neos2/r053_x.xxMx.xxR_400k_neos2.pbs.o4382
xxxxxxxx.xx.xxxxxxx:/data/xxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxx/summer2016/relax/r061_x.xxMx.xxR_20k_neos2/0R_20k_neos2.pbs.o4396
```

The `-t` (`--template`) specifies that we're looking for the value of (`-v`) the named nodes anywhere in the input document.  The `-nl` at the end makes XMLStarlet output a newline after the last data.

You may also pipe into XMLStarlet:

```
$ yourcommand | xmlstarlet sel ...
```

Answer (score -1):

Using only sed (with `-r` flag for extended regex)

```
echo "aaa string1 bbb aaa string2 bbb aaa string3 bbb" | sed -r 's/(aaa|bbb) ?//g'
```

Returns

```
string1 string2 string3
```

You also have this version using tr and grep (with `-vE`):

```
echo "aaa string1 bbb aaa string2 bbb aaa string3 bbb" | tr ' ' '\n'| grep -vE '(aaa|bbb|^$)'
```

Returns

```
string1
string2
string3
```

`tr` just replaces the space character with a newline.
`grep -vE` uses regex ("E") and excludes the matching lines ("v").

Third version uses sed (without flag) and grep (same as last version):

```
echo "aaa string1 bbb aaa string2 bbb aaa string3 bbb" | sed 's/\s/\n/g' | grep -vE '(aaa|bbb|^$)'
```

Doing pretty much the exact same thing as version two, using sed instead of tr.

Edit: Also added the `^$` in the grep search string to make sure it doesn't return unwanted newlines.

Edit2: I see you changed the OP. Above answer is to the original question. Below I've made a script that might help you out:
http://pastebin.com/uKWAGE0Y

Comment: -1 vote? Did I misunderstand the question?

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but I'm still getting the error `sed: -e expression #1, char 36: unknown option to \`s'`. The input was `echo $(qstat -x) | sed -r 's/(<Output_Path>|</Output_Path>) ?//g'`

Comment: Why the `echo` in the beginning? Try one of the following:  

A: `qstat -x |  sed -r 's/(aaa|bbb) ?//g'`

B: `qstat -x |  sed 's/\s/\n/g' | grep -vE '(aaa|bbb)'`  

C: `qstat -x |  tr ' ' '\n'| grep -vE '(aaa|bbb)'`

Comment: I tried all of those and none of them worked. I put the `echo` there in an attempt to make it work. `qstat -x | sed 's/\s/\n/g' | grep -vE '(<Output_Path>|</Output_Path>)'` does not result in an error, but it doesn't give the desired output (presumably the wrong output, too). `qstat -x | tr ' ' '\n'| grep -vE '(<Output_Path>|</Output_Path>)'` appears to do the same thing as the previous command.

Comment: Probably because I don't really understand the output you are getting. Your example might not be a good example? If you wish to match something like <foobar>*</foobar> (like html) you can probably do something like this.
`sed -r 's!</?Output_Path>!#D#!g;s! !\n!g' | sed -n '/#D#/p' | tr -d '#D#'`

Comment: @boof did this help you in any way? I'm still unsure how to help out more exactly if I don't know the exact formatting of your output (in other words, the exact output is not needed, just the way it is formatted (is it <aaa>string<bbb> or <aaa>string</aaa>? New lines after each line, or do the strings span over several lines? And so on, and so forth), if you catch my drift).

Comment: @boof See, this is what happens when you use random strings instead of realistic examples, because the file names might disclose "sensitive scientific information". If the file names contain slashes, `sed` will get confused. Use a different delimited.

Comment: @MichaelVehrs Thank you for the feedback. I should have asked my question better. The output I am using does contain slashes and other special characters.

Kaffe Myers: The solution has not worked yet. The strings are all on the same line and there are no new lines in the output that is being processed.

I will update my question with a better example.